# Can't make operator<< in iterator class inside another class

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, operator-overloading, ostream

So, i have class ArrayList, and inside, i have class iterator. I tried everything to make operator<< inside iterator class, to work with iterators, but nothing works. I tried with and without friend, in private and public, inline and outside the class, i have nothing else to try so if someone has some suggestion, feel free to say :D tyyy

also, i don't know does it have something with my problem, but ArrayList is template class

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ArrayList<T>::iterator & it)
{
    return os << *it;
}

template <typename T>
class ArrayList {
private:
    T* elements_;
    size_t size_;
    size_t capacity_;
public:
class iterator;
};

template <typename T>
class ArrayList<T>::iterator {
private:
    T* ptr_;
public:
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const iterator&);
};
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: This should be straightforward, so show us an example of what you have tried. You are obviously making some mistake, but it's hard to know what it is without seeing your code.

Comment: Please provide some snippeds of code

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList<T>::iterator` is a dependent name so it needs to be preceeded with `typename` keyword like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const typename ArrayList<T>::iterator & it) {
//                                               ^^^
    return os << *it;
}
```

and, of course, your `operator<<` overload should be defined after your class definition.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:18,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:18,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:18,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:18,startLineNumber:9),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvariant%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aclass+ArrayList+%7B%0Aprivate:%0A++++T*+elements_%3B%0A++++size_t+size_%3B%0A++++size_t+capacity_%3B%0A%0Apublic:%0A++++class+iterator%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aclass+ArrayList%3CT%3E::iterator+%7B%0Aprivate:%0A++++T*+ptr_%3B%0Apublic:%0A++++friend+std::ostream%26+operator%3C%3C(std::ostream%26,+const+iterator%26)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Astd::ostream%26+operator%3C%3C(std::ostream%26+os,+const+typename+ArrayList%3CT%3E::iterator+%26+it)%0A%7B%0A++++return+os+%3C%3C+*it%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.462659926022575,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'0'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:100,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),k:100,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:47.44155463336438,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

**UPDATE**

In order to resolve linking errors mentioned in the comments, try placing the `operator<<` overload body directly into the class body like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class ArrayList<T>::iterator {
private:
    T* ptr_;
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const iterator& it) {
        return os << *it;
    }
};
```

Comment: @vlasaks i believe that's the part you didn't show us?

Comment: @vlasaks at a guess probably due to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: @vlasaks try placing `operator<<` overload inline, as part of your class body

Comment: ty kind sir, and everyone else
the last one, inline worked, i tried the same thing without friend and it didn't, but now it's working :D ty again, i just spend 5h trying to solve it :D

Answer (score 0):

I would rather consider having operator *

```
template <typename T> class ArrayList {
private:
    T* elements_;
    size_t size_;
    size_t capacity_;
public:
    class iterator {
    private:
        T* ptr_;
    public:
        T operator *() {return *ptr_;}
    };
};
```

Now the operator << will work naturally for any type T that has operator defined, so you don't have to define it by yourself:

```
cout<< *it<< endl;
```

You will define the operator << only on typename T if it does not have operator defined. Normally you will not define it for int, char, string and so on.

Comment: but i need operator << to work directly with iterator

Comment: How exactly you need it to work directly with iterator? What exactly the operator has to do with iterator?

Comment: @vlasaks the iterator implements the paradigm of pointer. A pointer need such operators as ++ -- * -> + .... But streaming a pointer with << is not a correct operation with a pointer.

Comment: @vlasaks You have to see what the iterators do. The std containers iterators do not implement such an operator.